# Generating Random Number between 1 and 99 inclusive?

Tags: java, random

How do I use Math.random() to generate a random integer between 1 and 99, both inclusive?

Comment: oh sorry. Integer. This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if it works. 

firstRan= (int)(Math.random()*(99)) + 1;

Comment: Java or JavaScript or something else? (The basic formula you have is correct, BTW.)

Comment: It's in Java (BlueJ)

Comment: So it should generate a value that can be 1, 99, or any integer in between?

Comment: Yeah, that should be correct then (although you don't need parentheses on `(99)`).

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This works, make sure to `import java.util.Random`:

```
int max = 100;
int min = 1;
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int min =1;
int max = 99;  
 private static int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {

        if (min >= max) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("max must be greater than min");
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
```